# Java : Regexp without Stringbuffer

Tags: java, regex, bufferedreader

I had a big text file which contains multiple subtext, each delimited by `<text>` and `</text>` as shown as below

`<text>lots of text</text> <start>lots of text</text> ...`

My goal is to read the text file, extract information from each subtext and write these informations in three files everytime.

I thought about using this code to have a String

```
Path bigInputPath = Paths.get("bigfile.txt");
BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(bigInputPath, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
String l;
while ((l = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(l);
}
reader.close();
```

Then use regexp to extract the first subtext, work on it, then extract the second subtext and work on it etc...

But the text file is very huge, is there better way to proceed?

Comment: This looks like XML (except that `<start>` instead of `<text>` in your example) which suggests XML parser rather than regex (maybe [SAX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/sax/parsing.html)).

Comment: @Pshemo or [Stax](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/stax/using.html) (possibly through [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson)). Definitely **not** regex if it's markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the data is between tags you could parse it like an XML document I believe.

Here is an example on how to do so: https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/